# Can a UIViewController connect to different multiple UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

Based on the requirements, `HomeVC` will navigate to different VCs using segues.

I have the following structure:

```
          |- VC1
 HomeVC --|- VC2
          |- VC3
```

Can I create multiple segues to each of the VCs?

Example: HomeVC connects to `VC1` by a segue.

I drag the yellow icon on top of the `HomeVC` to `VC1` and name it `segueVC1`
and for `VC2` and `VC3`, I will use the same method.

I would like to know if this is permissible and OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it is permitted, moreover, a very common method to use segues this way. They can ease visualizing navigation between view controllers and help structuring the project.

Comment: I use UItableView Cell to drag to an UIViewController to create a Segue and button also has its own segue. Is this also ok?  Base on your  suggestion, I will create all segues base on an UIViewController next time.

Comment: Segue is the way of transition between different view controllers. I hope you can use this too. The only things is not permissible by apple is not to use the private methods and deprecated one.